# posix shell: reading entries with spaces from a textfile into variables

Tags: sh

I want to pass around (lots of) information between scripts, ideally having in- /output of a script persistent.
Using simple textfiles seems rather fitting, but problems arise as soon as entries have spaces.

Whats the preferable way of storing variables in one shell script and reading them in another?

In the examples below I expect the output to be

```
'publicname' 'x86' '"test directory"' '5' rem:'some other parameters in the future'
```

Version 1:
This would be my prefered format of the textfile, no escaping necessary, spaces would be entered within quotes.

```
echo 'publicname x86 "test directory" 5 some other parameters in the future
' >/tmp/input.txt
while read -r name archname vcdir rev rem; do
  set -e
  [ -n "$name" -a "$name" != "#" ] || continue
  echo "'$name' '$archname' '$vcdir' '$rev' rem:'$rem'"
done < /tmp/input.txt
```

Outputs

```
'publicname' 'x86' '"test' 'directory"' rem:'5 some other parameters in the future'
```

Version 2:
Produces correct output, put the input needs to be escaped for the shell. This is problematic since ideally the input would be used with other languages, and be generated by shell scripts too (need to escape variables for export)

```
echo 'publicname x86 test\ directory 5 some other parameters in the future
' >/tmp/input.txt
while read name archname vcdir rev rem; do
  set -e
  [ -n "$name" -a "$name" != "#" ] || continue
  echo "'$name' '$archname' '$vcdir' '$rev' rem:'$rem'"
done < /tmp/input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is: use a delimiter that can't appear in a field. Let's say a comma is safe:

```
echo 'publicname,x86,test directory,5,some other parameters in the future' > /tmp/input.txt
while IFS=, read -r name archname vcdir rev rem; do
  printf "'%s' '%s' '%s' '%s' rem:'%s'\n"  "$name" "$archname" "$vcdir" "$rev" "$rem"
done < /tmp/input.txt
```

If a comma could appear in a field, you might want to try a less-common delimiter, such as an ASCII control character.

```
printf 'publicname\037x86\037test directory\0375\037some other parameters in the future\n' > /tmp/input.txt
while IFS=$(printf '\037') read -r name archname vcdir rev rem; do
  printf "'%s' '%s' '%s' '%s' rem:'%s'\n"  "$name" "$archname" "$vcdir" "$rev" "$rem"
done < /tmp/input.txt
```

A simpler alternative is to use a newline, then call `read` multiple times.

```
printf 'publicname\nx86\ntest directory\n5\nsome other parameters in the future\n' > /tmp/input.txt
while read -r name; read -r archname; read -r vcdir; read -r rev; read -r rem; do
    printf "'%s' '%s' '%s' '%s' rem:'%s'\n"  "$name" "$archname" "$vcdir" "$rev" "$rem"
done < /tmp/input.txt
```

As a last resort, you can try using the null character as the delimiter. [No example, because I am blanking on how to handle null-delimited data in Posix shell, but if you've gotten this far without a feasible solution, shell is probably not the right language to be using.]